# Retrieving a vector item from a function through reference to shared_ptr

Tags: vector, stl, containers, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I need to fetch the item of vector placed in a unique_ptr from a function and modify it. The modification should reflect in the original container.

The data is strictly being maintained with locks, so no other thread can modify the container until I release it.

The below code does the work, but crashes at the end of the main function with: Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
. But why?
Same crash observed with unique_ptr as well.

Is there any other better way of fetching?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct Item
{
    int i;
};
struct Data
{
    vector<Item> vec;
};
unique_ptr<Data> dataPtr(new Data());

void create()
{
    Item w;
    w.i = 2;
    dataPtr->vec.push_back(w);
    cout << "Data added\n";
}
void GetItem(shared_ptr<Item>& work)
{
    auto &w = dataPtr->vec.front();
    work.reset(&w);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    create();
    shared_ptr<Item> oldItem;
    GetItem(oldItem);
    oldItem->i = 3;
    cout << "Retrieved Item: " << oldItem->i << endl;
    cout << "Global Item: " << dataPtr->vec.front().i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It can be done by passing a reference to pointer without issues. But I want to use C++11 features rather than raw pointers.

Comment: A `shared_ptr` can only wrap a pointer to an object allocated by `new`. When that `shard_ptr` goes out of scope, its destructor would call `delete` on the underlying raw pointer, which would exhibit undefined behavior unless it was allocated by `new`. In light of this, `work.reset(&w)` is illegal, and makes no sense. Why again do you feel the need to use `shared_ptr` here? You are not implementing shared ownership - all items are clearly owned by `dataPtr`.